# Automapper AutoMapper асинхронный IValueResolver?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

Есть IValueResolver

```
public class MyValueResolver : IValueResolver<Entity, Dto, List<InnerDto>>
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public MyValueResolver(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public List<InnerDto> Resolve(
        Entity source,
        Dto destination, 
        List<InnerDto> destMember, 
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        IEnumerable<InnerDto> innerDtos =
            _service.GetAsync(/*...*/).Result; // .Result block thread.

        return innerDtos.ToList();
    }
}
```

В теле `Resolve` есть вызов асинхронного метода. Сейчас можно использовать свойство `.Result`, однако это блокирует поток что не есть хорошо.

Если какой либо аналог асинхронный `IValueResolver`. Асинхронный `IMappingAction` тоже будет отлично.

Update:
Используется это так:

```
CreateMap<Entity, Dto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.InnerDtos, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyValueResolver>());
```

Comment: Здесь об этом пишут: `https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/991` но решения там нету

Comment: Может обернуть `Resolve()` в Task?

Comment: @NewView, `IValueResolver<Entity, Dto, Task<List<InnerDto>>>` ? Так то можно, только тогда оно будет на уровень выше засетить свойство типа `List<InnerDto>` значением `Task<List<InnerDto>>` и `await` в `ForMember` тоже не напишешь

Comment: Может так: `public await List<InnerDto> Resolve(..) { Task.Start => .. }` ?

Comment: @NewView, В C# так нельзя. Если заменить `public await` на `public async` - тогда нужно возвращать `Task<>`, при этом возвращаемый тип задаётся интерфейсом, что не даст присвоить в `List<>` `Task<>` в `MapperProfile`. Или напишите полный код в ответ.

Comment: `MyValueResolver : IValueResolver<Entity, Dto, Task<List<InnerDto>>>`

Comment: Без реализации библиотечного интерфейса кажется `await Task.Run(MyValueResolver.Resolve())` должен превратить это в конструкцию в реальный асинхронный метод с context-switch у потока из thread pool.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Я так пробовал. В таком случае нужно что бы в `CreateMap<Entity, Dto>().ForMember(x => x.InnerDtos)`, свойство `InnerDtos` было тоже `Task<>`. Иначе придется ставить `.Result` в методе `ForMember`. Что по сути тоже самое, что есть сейчас.

Comment: @Gordory, без реализации библиотечного интерфейса, Automapper не даст написать `MapFrom` в методе `ForMember`.

Comment: `.ForMember(async x => await x.InnerDtos)` — так не сработает?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, к сожалению нет. И AutoMapper внутри не `await`тит метод `Resolve()`